# Bitcoin Util Grind

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

What's "bitcoin-util grind" for?

```
  grind
       Perform proof of work on hex header string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It performs proof-of-work mining; given a block header, it finds a nonce such that the header with the nonce in it hashes to a value below the proof-of-work target.

Its purpose is assisting with signet creation. In signet, blocks have a small amount of proof-of-work (they're relatively low difficulty), but also require a signature by the (fixed) signers for the network. In order to assist these signers in their block-creation process, the `grind` command of `bitcoin-util` can be invoked.

To be clear, this feature is not useful for normal mainnet or even testnet mining:

- It is CPU only, unable to take advantage of specific hardware like GPUs, FPGAs, or ASICs.
- Even for a CPU-only mining tool, it is slow. It lacks optimizations that could speed it up, in order to improve maintainability and simplicity of the code.
- It has no interface to interact with mining protocols like Stratum or GBT.